# Ce n’est pas l’/ un épisode d’une aventure

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> La nouvelle a une fin. Parce qu’elle cherche à surprendre, ce n’est
> pas l’épisode d’une aventure.

([règlement](https://salondulivre-somain.webnode.fr/_files/200002707-71b6a71b6d/R%C3%A8glement%202021.pdf))

Une aventure a plusieurs épisodes. Est-ce qu'il aurait été préférable d'écrire "ce n’est
pas un épisode d’une aventure" ? Comment expliquer l'emploi de l'article défini dans cette phrase ?

Answer (score 5):

*Ce n'est pas **un** épisode d'une aventure* est possible mais la forme avec l'article défini bien plus naturelle.

Peut-être est-ce la répétition/proximité de *un* et *une* qui est lourde car par exemple *ce n'est pas un épisode parmi d'autres* serait très bien passé. Ou peut-être est-ce simplement le fait que l'on considère que la nouvelle est déjà écrite dans le règlement (elle est décrite au présent), qu'elle est donc définie qui justifie qu'on la compare avec un épisode qui est de ce fait lui-aussi défini.

Answer (score -1):

Préliminaire à la décision du choix de tel article plutôt que de tel autre, il est nécessaire de connaitre la nature du mot pour lequel on considère ce choix. Or il est assez apparent qu'il y a un quiproquo sur la nature du mot « épisode ». Il est instructif, dans le but de mieux s'en convaincre, d'examiner le texte dans lequel se trouve l'extrait cité dans la question.

> La nouvelle tourne autour d'**un évènement**, avec **peu de personnages**. Parce qu'elle est concentrée, la nouvelle ne raconte pas l'épisode d'un héros, d'une société sur une longue période (contrairement au roman).
>
> la nouvelle a **une fin**. Parce qu'elle cherche à surprendre, ce n'est pas l'épisode d'une aventure. Elle doit surprendre ou interroger le lecteur avant la fin. La fin d'une nouvelle peut-être une chute ou laisser du mystère, mais elle clôt l'évènement, le sujet.

On trouve une première occurrence du mot dans la proposition « la nouvelle ne raconte pas **l'épisode d'un héros**… ». Si on prend pour définition du mot « épisode », comme ça l'est fait implicitement dans la question, la définition suivante du TLFi,

> « [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9pisode) : 2. Division d'une œuvre qui comprend plusieurs parties dont chacune forme un tout pouvant se suffire à lui-même. »,

on s'aperçoit que « épisode d'un héros » n'a pas de sens ; on peut, selon l'acception citée ci-dessus, parler  de tel ou tel épisode parmi tous les épisodes d'une histoire, ou parmi ceux-ci de l'épisode qui traite de tels ou tels faits, ou encore, de l'épisode où le/un héros se trouve dans une certaine situation, etc. « Épisode d'un héros » n'est pas définissable par simple compositionnalité, et ce n'est pas non plus un composé défini dans les dictionnaires.  La  définition suivante du TLFi (B2) nous sort de cette impasse.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9pisode)) **B.** − P. ext.
> **1.**  […]
> **2.** **Moment plus ou moins marquant de la vie de quelqu'un**.
> ♦ Épisode dramatique.
> ♦ Ma vie continue à se passer sans le moindre épisode.  (Flaub., Corresp.,1873, p. 93)
> ♦ Sa tête était toute pleine d'épisodes de sa vie passée (Aymé, Travelingue,1941, p. 183).

Donc, si « épisode » signifie « passage plus ou moins marquant de la vie de quelqu'un », il s'ensuit que « *épisode d'un héros* » s'explique naturellement. Cependant, pourquoi parler de « **l'** épisode » ? Quoi dans le contexte devrait nous laisser supposer que ce héros n'aurait été sujet dans sa vie qu'à un seul passage marquant, quoi nous laisse entendre qu'on parle  d'un passage en particulier au cas où plusieurs passages marquants sont discernables ? Rien. Il n'y a donc pas de justification pour le déterminant « le ». Seulement « un » convient.

L'examen de ce premier cas montre que dans celui de l'occurrence de « épisode » qui concerne la question, il y a peu de doute qu'« épisode » n'a encore rien à voir avec l'idée de « division » d'une œuvre. Encore une fois, en rapport avec cette idée la construction n'a pas de sens ; « épisode d'une aventure » ne signifie rien : on peut parler d'un épisode d'un livre, d'un épisode dans le récit de telle ou telle aventure, etc. En ce qui concerne cette nouvelle construction, on voit que la définition suivante du TLFi peut lui donner du sens, cependant, on n'a pas une construction idiomatique : l'auteur ramène le domaine d'application de ce terme à des phénomènes d'une importance dérisoire en comparaison de ceux dans lesquels il prend son sens : les guerres, l'émancipation de la femme, la colonisation, l'évolution de l'homme, la décadence de Rome, l'industrialisation, le temps des Girondins, etc. ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A9pisode%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=gKkrYfeJFfCZlwSzpqHIBg&start=100&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj3yYrZx9byAhXwzIUKHTNTCGkQ8tMDegQIARBE&biw=958&bih=1008&dpr=1) ; l'usage dévie très peu.).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9pisode)) **B.** − P. ext.
> **1.** **Ensemble d'actions, d'événements formant un tout et constituant un moment marquant de l'histoire, du temps**
> ♦  Épisode d'une guerre
> ♦ raconter un épisode
> ♦ épisodes successifs
> ♦ les principaux épisodes
> ♦ La guerre de l'Indépendance américaine n'a été par le fait qu'un épisode de la rivalité anglo-française.  (Bainville, Hist. Fr.,t. 2, 1924, p. 14)

En acceptant cet usage, non idiomatique, mais le seul possible pour donner du sens à cette combinaison de mots, ce dont il est question c'est de l'ensemble des actions, des évènements propres à une aventure donnée, (l'épisode d'une aventure). Il est évident que cet ensemble est unique ; il est donc nécessaire d'utiliser l'article défini.

Comment: Le choix des articles n'est pas lié à ces noms en particulier. C'est un phénomène général que pour exprimer « [article] A de [article] B » lorsqu'on ne fait référence ni à un A en particulier ni à un B en particulier, c'est-à-dire qu'on voudrait a priori mettre un article indéfini à A et à B, on dit habituellement « un A de B » ou « l'A d'un B » et rarement « un A d'un B ».

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Pas du tout d'accord… « le cœur de la ville » et non « un cœur de la ville » (il n'y en a qu'un), « un coin de la ville » et non « le coin de la ville » (qui ne se dira jamais).

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre explication, je vais la relire bientôt.